# Capture the soundcard's output?

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to get the data that the soundcard is outputting. Unfortunately, from my understanding of the Java Sound API, SourceDataLine does not support the read method, and there is no way to listen for raw data. I want to stick to Java for this, rather than C++, so if anyone knows how to listen for audio output on the soundcard that would be great.

Thanks very much!

Sorry if this post is confusing, just woke up.

Comment: Did you try this first? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

Comment: yes that doesn't help

Answer (score 3):

I've researched this a while, and determined any implementation using only java sound will not work with any reliability on multiple audio cards.

There are a few solutions though.  Hopefully one of these helps you.

1. Bite the bullet, write some C++ code to allow this functionality on different operating systems.
2. Use Java Sound to capture audio from a virtual audio recorder adapter which loops back the system audio output.
3. Create a loopback yourself using cables to feed a sound output port into a sound input port.

I recommend option 1 if you're developing this for a professional application as installation will be cleaner.

Go with option 2 if you've a short amount of time, and you expect to spend more time with your users, or your users are tech savvy.

Use option 3 if this is just a hobby, or some one-off project for a client.

Comment: all 3 options require some sort of c++. I guess I'll have to

Comment: No they don't, only option 1 requires C++.  With 2 and 3 you can use pure Java Sound to access specific recording devices.  Those recording devices will be feeding you audio output.

Comment: Yea William. I guess I'll just have to learn more about that data is formatted. I assume it's raw when in bytes

Comment: If you target windows 10 and like to go for option 2 - make use of javax.sound capture via OS provided mixer - you can use as input device the Stereo Mix (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/)